# Drupal for Bloggers: How can I achive getting such a little FB, Twitter, etc. Box on the left of my homepage?

Tags: social-network

How can I achive getting such a little, sticky FB, Twitter, etc. Box on the left of my homepage, like one can find on this site:
http://www.marieforleo.com/2010/04/real-online-paid/

Any ideas - or is there a module for that?
Sorry I don't know what this little box is called ...

Many thanks!
Soezkan

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about implementing a functionality or a layout seen in a site, for which just a description of the feature, a screenshot, or a site URL is provided. See [Help Center](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

You want to try something like the [ShareBar](https://www.drupal.org/project/sharebar) in Drupal 7.

> The Drupal Sharebar module lets you easily add a "floating" social
>   media submission bar on your website (like that found on Mashable)
>   that includes share buttons for the most popular social media websites
>   online such as Facebook, Twitter, and Google +1 Buttons.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks tenken! THis is exactly what I was looking for! great.